# How to create a custom buttom using the new Google (gsi)?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to migrate https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client library to https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client using an HTML script in my web project.

I'm following this migration orientations https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis

With the last library I used auth2.attachClickHandler method to associate the button with the Google popup opening. My button was custumized and it had an own design.

This old method returns an id_token.

While migrating to the new gsi library I found out that I should use Google's own button which is render on my page as an iframe. Only this way I could get the id_token (today called **credential**).

Is there any way to get the user id_token (credential) using my custom designed button?

Comment: Queira seguir as orientações do link "Melhore a pergunta" do quadro de fechamento,  já apresentado [da 1 vez que perguntou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/558288/70) - duplicação de postagens não é permitido aqui. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentários aqui foi desativado, mas vou deixar mais uns links que podem ajudar naquela 1a versão, onde o campo de comentários está ativo.